# Debian - LAMP Install

Tags: linux, shell, unix, touch, lamp

I am installing a LAMP install on Debian GNU/Linux and have been asked to enter the following command

```
sudo touch /var/www/info.php
```

I was just wondering if anyone could explain what it does.

Thanks

Jack

Comment: try this: `man sudo`

Comment: then that: `man touch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command creates an empty file called "info.php". The next step is probably to edit the file, and add something like this to it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

What this does is allow you to see all information about your Apache/PHP installation through your browser, usually to see if you have all the PHP libraries you need.

When you have done installing, you should delete "info.php".

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` raises the privilege level of the following command to superuser level (root). In this case the following command is `touch`, and `touch` creates the file that is passed as parameter, in this case `/var/www/info.php`.

The best you can do is read the `man` pages of `sudo` and `touch`.